# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Tags: javascript

Trying to use the following code in a page test.html:

```
<script language = "javascript">
function test()
{
    if (typeof a != "undefined")
    {
        document.body.innerHTML = "";
        document.write(a);
    }
    else
    {
        document.body.innerHTML = "";
        document.write("a is undefined");
    }
    var a = "a is defined";
    document.write("<br><br>");
    document.write("<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='function(){ test(a); }'>test</a>");
}
window.onload = function(){ test(); }
</script>
```

Results in the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (". How would I get the link to clear the page and display the corresponding variable?

Comment: does it change when you omit the spaces between language="javascript" ?

Comment: The problem with his code (actually, one of it - not the syntax error) is that the function inside the string does not create a closure.

Comment: Which line is shown to contain the error?

Comment: Hi Andreas, if you mean changing language = "javascript" to language="javascript" then no, nothing changes. SE

Comment: I don't see your error, but I also don't see the function getting executed at all (adding an alert to the beginning of the script does nothing.) So I suspect the problem to be at the last line.

Comment: Is this error browser specific because I don't get an error in either IE8, IE7 or FF7?

Comment: The question is not so much the error I got as to why the javascript won't work, but yes, it doesn't appear in FF7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `function(){ test(a); }` inside your onclick is the cause of the error.

You'd need to use `(function(){ test(a); })` to get a function *expression* instead of a function *statement*.

However, since `a` is not global and JavaScript inside an HTML `on*` argument won't create a closure the code still doesn't work.

---

Here's a [proper/working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/hVuCp/) using jQuery:

```
function test(a) {
    if(a !== undefined) {
        $('body').html(a);
    }
    else {
        $('body').html('a is undefined');
    }
    var a = 'a is defined';
    $('body').append('<br /><br />');
    $('<a href="#">test</a>').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        test(a);
    }).appendTo('body');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    test();
});
```

Comment: perhaps i'm mistaken, but wouldn't `window.onload = test;` also work? (no brackets)

Comment: @Mark: Then you cannot be sure that no arguments are passed. Besides that, document.ready triggers earlier (as soon as the DOM is ready) which is usually what one wants - no need to wait for images being loaded etc.

Comment: Do you think there is ANY way this could be done in normal Javascript? SE

Comment: Yes. But the code will be way less nice than with jQuery. And looking at the tiny size and permissive licenses of jQuery, there should be no reason not to include it.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Use `$(test);` then. Much shorter ;)

Comment: @SystemError: Can always look at the source code and find how they implemented the `ready` function.

Comment: @Mark: That will pass jQuery to test since the first argument of the ready event is the global jQuery function.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Ooo...good call sir! Perhaps I should stop doing this in my code >.< Haha... probably doesn't hurt when the function *actually* takes no arguments though.